# Multi Threaded App With Issues Aquiring DB Connections

Tags: java, mysql, spring, multithreading, hibernate

I have a Java application that reads data from a CSV file, turns them into business objects, and then saves them to a db. Most of the work is done single-threaded, but some of it is done using multiple threads. The application uses Spring framework, Hibernate as the ORM provider, c3p0 as the connection pool provider, and MySQL as the database. The parts of the application which are multi-threaded are annotated with @Async, using a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor created as a bean for the TaskExecutor that will do this work. The @Aysnc annotated methods return CompletableFuture.

With a small CSV file (under 10k records) everything is fine. However, some of our clients have much larger files (150k records) and this increase in load produces issues during the multi-threaded portions of the application. Here is one of the @Async annotated methods:

```
public class AppointmentTreeDAO {

    @Autowired
    private AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppointmentTreeDAO.class);

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Appointment> getObjectTree(Long oldApptId) {
        logger.info("getting appointment thread");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(appointmentRepository.findByApptId(oldApptId));
    }
}
```

This is the AppointmentRepository class (the last method is the one the code in question is calling):

```
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long> {

    List<Appointment> findByAccountId(String accountId);
    List<Appointment> findByAccountIdAndProductIdAndApptStartDatetimeBetween(String accountId,
            String productId, Date startDate, Date endDte);
    Slice<Appointment> findByAccountIdAndProductIdAndApptStartDatetimeBetween(String accountId,
            String productId, Date startDate, Date endDte, Pageable pageable);

    @Query(value = "select a.appt_id from appointment a where a.appt_start_datetime " +
            "between :startDate AND :endDate and a.account_id = :accountId and a.product_id = :productId",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Long> findByApptIdBetween(@Param("startDate") String startDate, @Param("endDate") String endDate,
                                   @Param("accountId") String accountId, @Param("productId") String productId);

    Appointment findByApptId(Long apptId);
}
```

Since I have that log line in the AppointmentTreeDAO class, I am able to see in the logs that each thread is doing work:

```
2:58:12.771 PM  
2021-11-11 14:58:12.771  INFO 1 --- [mtSave-38] c.t.etl.repository.AppointmentTreeDAO    : getting appointment thread
```

Eventually, I start seeing exceptions like this from the threads (same thread as above in this case):

```
2:58:16.790 PM  
2021-11-11 14:58:16.790  WARN 1 --- [mtSave-38] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08001

2:58:16.803 PM  
2021-11-11 14:58:16.803 ERROR 1 --- [mtSave-38] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

2:58:16.804 PM  
2021-11-11 14:58:16.804  WARN 1 --- [mtSave-38] c.t.etl.pipeline.load.Loader     : java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$doSubmit$3(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:279)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy148.findByApptId(Unknown Source)
    at com.etl.repository.AppointmentTreeDAO.getObjectTree(AppointmentTreeDAO.java:25)
    at com.etl.repository.AppointmentTreeDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fb95149d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.lambda$doSubmit$3(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:276)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:903)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor129.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:847)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address (Address not available)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63)
    ... 75 more


2:58:16.804 PM  
2021-11-11 14:58:16.804  WARN 1 --- [mtSave-38] c.t.etl.pipeline.load.Loader     : Thread 77 ProcessFutures Loop Exception: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Soon after throwing the above exception it starts doing work again and its now able to call the db when it couldn't just a short time ago:

```
2:58:16.807 PM  
2021-11-11 14:58:16.807  INFO 1 --- [mtSave-38] c.t.etl.repository.AppointmentTreeDAO    : getting appointment thread
```

This happens intermittently with many different threads, if not all. But eventually all the work is complete and all futures are returned from that method. Then the application returns to being single threaded and the exceptions stop. Once the application returns to using multiple threads the same exceptions as above occur again.

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false" />
            <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="ALWAYS" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="54"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        </properties>
```

This is how the TaskExecutor is created:

```
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        logger.info("Creating Async Task Executor");
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(45);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(45);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("mtSave-");
        executor.initialize();
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(120);
        return executor;
    }
```

I have autoReconnect=true&maxReconnects=10 on my db connection string.

It seems like the threads are being starved for a connection, but I don't understand why. There will always be more work items than there are threads. 150k records of work compared to 45 threads on the high end, and under 10k records of work on the low end. The application never threw these exceptions until multi threading was introduced. I have the connection pool max size (54) set higher than the number of threads I have (45).

Ive tried changing the number of threads, the max size of the connection pool, different size files and did tons of research. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Java / JDBC connections aren't thread safe so each thread creates its own connections.

And, MySQL servers limit the number of simultaneous connections they allow. That's a hard limit set at MySQL server startup time. So it's possible your JDBC code in all your threads is attempting to make more connections than the server allows, and so the server rejects them. The app responds with the exceptions you saw.

> org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection;

There's another factor to keep in mind. Concurrent queries to the same table (INSERTs or anything else) can contend with one another. Paradoxically, you may get much better throughput with a much smaller number of threads. Try four threads.

If you give the command `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Connection%'` you'll see a count of connection errors.  Give the command before and after you run your program and take the difference between the values.  The values look like this.

```
Connection_errors_accept           errors that occurred during calls to accept() on the listening port.
Connection_errors_internal         connections refused due to internal errors in the server, such as failure to start a new thread or an out-of-memory condition.
Connection_errors_max_connections  connections refused because the server max_connections limit was reached.
Connection_errors_peer_address     errors while searching for connecting client IP addresses.
Connection_errors_select           errors during calls to OS select() or poll() on the listening port. (Failure of this operation does not necessarily means a client connection was rejected.)
Connection_errors_tcpwrap          connections refused by the libwrap library.
Connections                        connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.
```

Comment: This is interesting. I’ll try a smaller number of threads tomorrow and also take a look at what that MySQL command returns. 

If the JDBC code is attempting to make more connections than the server allows, wouldn’t the same be true when under a much lighter load with a file that has under 10k records? There is still the same number of threads of 45. And isn’t the c3p0 connection pool limiting the number of simultaneous  connections to the server?